# C# how to set a class attribute value dynamically in an ActionLink?

Tags: c#, attributes, actionlink, html.actionlink

I have an ActionLink that looks like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink(Model.Name, "Details", "Appointments", new { id = Model.Id }, new { @class = "btn btn-default" })
```

It works, but I would like to enhance it to something that can change the height of the rendered button according to a Size property in the Model. I have not figured out how to write that piece of code and get it to work. I want something like this in "pseudo-code:

```
@Html.ActionLink(Model.Name, "Details", "Appointments", new { id = Model.Id }, new { @class = "btn btn-default", height=Model.Size })
```

I hope someone would be able to show how this could should be written for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding style to your action link

```
style="height: @(Model.size+"px")" 

@Html.ActionLink(Model.Name, "Details", "Appointments", new { id = Model.Id }, new { @class = "btn btn-default" , @style="height: @(Model.size+"px")" })
```

Comment: I tried but it had no effect. I wonder if the btn and btn-default classes' attribute values override the attempted Style.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that works, in the direction you pointed ashik! Thank you for your help.

```
@Html.ActionLink(Model.Name, "Details", "Appointments", new { id = Model.Id }, new { @class = "btn btn-default", @style = @Model.Size })
```

It works by assigning for instance the string "height: 100px" to the Size property of the viewmodel in the controller.